# Minimum price selection

Tags: sql, algorithm

Situation looks like this:

We have product 'A123' and we have to remember lowest price for it. 
Prices for one product comes from random number of shops and there is no way to tell when shop x will send us their price for 'A123'.

So I had SQL table with columns:

```
product_number
price
shop (from which shop this price comes)
```

An SQL function for updating product price looks like this (this is SQL pseudo-code, syntax doesn't matter):

```
function update_product(in_shop, in_product_number, in_price)
    select price, shop into productRow from products where product_number = in_product_number;
    if found then
        if (productRow.price > in_price) or (productRow.price < in_price and productRow.shop = in_shop) then
            update row with new price and new shop
        end if;
    else
       insert new product that we didn't have before
    end if;
```

the (productRow.price < in_price and productRow.shop = in_shop) condition is to prevent situation like this:

In products table we have

```
A123 22.5 amazon
```

then comes info from amazon again:

```
A123 25 amazon
```

Thanks to above condition we update price to higher which is correct behavior.

But algorithm fails in this situation: again we have a row in the products table:

```
A123 22.5 amazon
```

then comes info from merlin

```
A123 23 merlin (we don't update because price is higher)
```

then comes info from amazon

```
A123 35 amazon
```

and we update table and now we have:

```
A123 35 amazon
```

but this is wrong because merlin earlier has lower price for that product.

Any idea how to avoid this situation?

Comment: So you are taking minimum of the maximum price per vendor? You will need to save (vendor, maxprice_vendor) for all vendors, and then select the minimum from all the maxprice_* values.

Comment: the same comment like in other answers ;) solution with keeping max price for all suppliers is obvious but in such table will be few milion records and I am afraid that querying it would be slow...

Comment: Not max price but latest price. And query would not be slow if you use a database. Databases use indexed access instead of searching through all the records.

Comment: Well, you can use an indexed view or materialized view to optimize querying; worst case you can use triggers so that whenever you modify that table, the smaller table of lowest prices is also updated. The task is clearly impossible if you don't keep Merlin's earlier price around somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you are going to solve your problem is keep track of the price per shop and then only return the lowest current price.  So for example you would need a table like the one you already have, but when you select out of the table something like:

```
select min(price)
  from products
  where product_number = :my_product
```

Personally if it were me, I would keep a time stamp of when you receive the product price updates so you would be able to ascertain when you got the update.

Comment: Yes I could do that but the reason for not keeping price for all suppliers is performance. In table in which i would keep all prices from all suppliers there would be few milions of records

Comment: A few million records isn't really much of anything for a modern database.

Comment: Agreed, with an index on product_number, it would be relatively trivial.  And unless you have lots (like 10,000+) shops, then dealing with min or even updates over that few rows will be trivial as well.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you should maintain a table that contains the following:

- Product
- Supplier
- LatestPrice

Then identify the current best supplier by querying that table - you can either do this when requested or when the table is updated either way you simplify the problem at the price of slightly more complex schema and queries

Additional (following comment):

Ok, this is going to mean that you need to store more data - but you don't have a huge amount of choice - the data is required to solve the problem so you either: a) have to update prices from all suppliers concurrently and then choose the best price from that snapshot or b) store the prices as you get them and pick the best price from the data you've got. The former implies a fairly hefty overhead in terms of fetching and processing data whereas the latter is basically a fairly modest storage problem and something any decent databases will cope with easily.

Comment: Yes I could that but the reason for not keeping price for all suppliers is performance. In table in which i would keep all prices from all suppliers there would be few milions of records.

Comment: Only a few million records - the DBMS shouldn't have any problems with that small of a table.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem is that you only store the lowest price from 1 vendor. You have to keep records of prices of all vendors, and use a selection query to select the minimum.

For example, If you have:

```
A123 22.5 Amazon
```

and you got:

```
A123 23 Merlin
```

You have to insert it, even if it is with higher price, because it's a different vendor. So you'll have:

```
A123 22.5 Amazon
A123 23 Merlin
```

When you get the new price from Amazon, for example: 25, you just update it. So you'll get:

```
A123 25 Amazon
A123 23 Merlin
```

then select the lowest price, Merlin, in this case.